# RadGridView Binding Issue When Edit cell with Empty string

Tags: c#, sql-server, telerik-grid

I have RadGridView control in windows form application and I am binding its dataSource with a collection of Employees using Entity Framework data model entity that refers. this collection is mapping with the SQL Server Database table with the following columns

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
```

When I trying to edit Name column in the RadGridView and clear its text, this throw an Exception with the message : "This property cannot be set to a null value."

how to avoid this exception without making the column in the database allowing null.

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1):

try this
make a class that contains all the properties of table Employee

```
public class EmployeeData
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

after retrieving data from database make a list of class EmployeeData
say `List<EmployeeData>` and fill all properties of Employee data and set grid's data source that list and that will work.

for example

```
List<EmployeeData> emplyoee = new List<EmployeeData>();

//code for retrieving data and set into employee list.

yourgrid.datasource = employee;
yourgrid.databind();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But I want to use the Entity framework and solve the issue without need to change the business objects.